# *= Operator equivalent in 90 or later

Tags: sql, function, migration

I am preparing for a migration and have a stored procedure that uses the operator *=
which I know is a left outer join. This DB is in compatbility mode 80 (SQL Server 2000) but on a 2005 box. 
I am going to 2008R2 (mode 100). 
The functionality *= is not supported in 90 or later compatibility, 
So my question is will the stored procedure continue to work if I simply change the '*=' to 'LEFT OUTER JOIN'

Hopefully I gave all information needed to answer the question.

Regards

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried it yet I ran the 2008 Upgrade Advisor and this question came up form one of the bullets in the report it generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** you can use the LEFT JOIN as an equivalent. Also do ensure that you have used the proper syntax for LEFT JOIN.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> SQL Server supports both the SQL-92 outer join syntax and a legacy
>   syntax for specifying outer joins based on using the `*= and =*`
>   operators in the WHERE clause. The SQL-92 syntax is recommended
>   because it is not subject to the ambiguity that sometimes results from
>   the legacy Transact-SQL outer joins.